# Jest - some tests fail on the first run, but pass on the second and third run

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs, supertest

I write tests with jest and supertest npm, in node server.

when I run all the tests together, some of the tests fails:

[image: failing tests]

choosing in the terminal to run just the failed tests, run them and they pass.

[image: passing tests]

now, if I choose in the terminal to run all the tests again, all tests passes but the following error is shown:

> Watch Usage: Press w to show more.(node:9484) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

[image: error: unhandled promise rejection]

I use the `beforeEach()` to delete the db and create the initial db to be the same for each test.

this is `setUpDb()`:

```
const setUpDb = async () => {
    await neo4jContext('MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n')
    await usersRepository.addUser(user1)
    await usersRepository.addUser(user2)
    await productsRepository.addProduct({ userId: user1.id, product: product1 })
    await productsRepository.addProduct({ userId: user1.id, product: product2 })
    await storesRepository.addStore({
        userId: user1.id, store: store1, products: [product3]
    })
    await storesRepository.addStore({
        userId: user1.id, store: store2, products: [product3]
    })
}
```

//

```
beforeEach(setUpDb)
```

using `--runInBand` the tests run sequently, one after the other, so there should not be a mix-up state.

this is the config in the package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js",
    "debug": "env-cmd -f ./config/dev.env node inspect src/index.js",
    "dev": "env-cmd -f ./config/dev.env nodemon src/index.js",
    "test": "env-cmd -f ./config/test.env jest --watch --runInBand"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testTimeout": 50000
  }
```

I tried looking into it but all I found was tests that affect a common state, and therefor different result appears when run alone.
I'm don't think this is the issue here, because all of the above.

thx for anyone reaching out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it happened because I had a test with async function in it, that i didn't put await before it's execution:

```
it('should do something', async () => {
const asyncFunc = async () => console.log('async func needs await on exe')

//wrong
asyncFunc()
//right
await asyncFunc()
})
```